# How to fix prevent event on parent effect child

Tags: javascript, html

I set preventDefault in parent node like

```
document.querySelector(".aui-dialog").addEventListener("touchmove", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

then I added a child div, I used javascript (insertAdjacentHTML) `.aui-dialog` and set the child div css with `height(height:100px)` and `overscroll-y:scroll`

I found that the child div can not scroll when touchmove, After I try to remove the `e.preventDefault()` then it moves

Question: 
How can I Make the child scroll with parent node add `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: take a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27245600/javascript-preventdefault-only-on-parent-item
looks like duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript preventDefault only on parent item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27245600/javascript-preventdefault-only-on-parent-item)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to call the `event.stopPropagation()` method in the childs event listener?

The **[event.stopPropagation()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_stoppropagation.asp)** stops the bubbling of an event to parent elements, preventing any parent event handlers from being executed.

Comment: I have tried to add stopPropagation in child node but it will bubbling to root div dom

Comment: @jansma Please share your full code - I'm pretty sure there must be another problem! I'm pretty sure the **stopPropagation-call** should do the job.

Comment: I have repair it use https://github.com/joelambert/ScrollFix , thx